# How to reduce database (SQL Server) calls from .NET windows application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, optimization, architecture

I have a list of objects. For each object in that list, I call a stored procedure to save that object. I then get output from that stored procedure to set the object's `ID` property. So, if I have a list of 100 objects, I am calling the database 100 times.

To optimize this, I am planning to use XML as stored procedure's parameter. List of objects will be represented by hierarchical XML and stored procedure will parse the XML and call 100 insert / update based on XML values. I am not sure how to get the return values for each object. Could you help please? Do you have any other thoughts to optimize it? I use ADO.NET only no ORM like Entity Framework.

Answer (score 6):

Use Table Value Parameter and do the inserts/updates in your stored procedure and then select the rows changed to get all your IDs in a single call to the database. Google TVP in C# and SQL Server and you will find many examples of how to do that.

Comment: Thanks Tyler  ! I did not know about it. I was trying to use old XML instead. ha ha.  + 1 for this.